# Select points from a table that exist in a custom polygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon

We have a property search site where the user draws a polygon on a map and then the app displays all properties that fall within the polygon.

We have properties stored within a Postgres table that included the longitude and latitude values for each individual property (ie: `Property.Id`, `Property.Longitude`, `Property.Latitude`)

Example of the points of the polygon drawn by the user:

```
-83.39258193445859 42.5188864690573, -83.3550447440939 42.51981388191728, -83.34222679201048 42.50184518501131, -83.38033561769407 42.49526380665137, -83.41707115236205 42.505135614429214, -83.39155196619687 42.51896997517796, -83.39258193445859 42.5188864690573
```

How would I write a Postgres/PostGIS query that finds all records in my property table where the long/lat fall within the polygon coordinates displayed above?

Comment: You want PostGIS, the `geography` data type, and `ST_Within`.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't sound like you are storing this data in a spatially enabled database. You might benefit greatly from doing this.

Instead of storing the latitude and longitude separately, you could store them in a geometry column. Then, you can use the [st_within](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.3/ch06.html) function to do the query for you.

Comment: Used the answer above to solve my problem, but I can't post my answer until tomorrow as I'm a new user to the forum.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found.

Using the recommendation above, I added "Geometry" based column to the table and populated it using the `ST_MakePoint` function as shown below:

```sql
UPDATE "Property"
Set "Geom" = ST_SetSRID(
    ST_MakePoint("Property"."Longitude", "Property"."Latitude"), 
    3078);
```

I then used the `ST_Within` function to see if the Geometry based points falls within my custom polygon using the `ST_GeomFromText` function and my closed polygon points.

```sql
SELECT 
    "Property"."MLSNumber", 
    "Property"."Longitude", 
    "Property"."Latitude"
FROM "Property"
WHERE ST_Within("Property"."Geom", 
    ST_GeomFromText(
        'POLYGON(-83.39258193445859 42.5188864690573, 
        -83.3550447440939 42.51981388191728, 
        -83.34222679201048 42.50184518501131, 
        -83.38033561769407 42.49526380665137,
        -83.39258193445859 42.5188864690573)'
    )
)
```

The result "appears" to be correct but I have not yet plotted the polygon and returned points on a map to confirm it.

Comment: -1 for following the instructions from notkilroy and posting this as own answer. Even if your answer is more detailed.